# Toggle and Filter JavaScript function - combine

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two JavaScript functions: one toggles (hide/show) a table row when a link is clicked, and another that filters table rows (showing only rows with text that's entered into a text field). When someone enters text into the text field, I want to be able to hide all of the shown table rows (that were toggled). So, basically, I'm trying to add part of the toggle function to the filter function. The toggle function needs to function on its own, but all items will be hidden when text is entered.

**Toggle Function**

If a table row has an ID (id="celltohid1" or id="celltohid1"), then the following function hides or shows that row when a link it clicked...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'table-row')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'table-row';
    }
//-->
</script>
```

**Filter Function**

Below is the Filter function...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".search").on("keyup",function(){
            var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            $("#DMTbl tbody tr.contentrow").each(function(){
                var lineStr = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                if(lineStr.indexOf(searchTerm) === -1){
                    $(this).hide();
                }else{
                    $(this).show();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Goal (and my weak attempt)**

I need to add functionality that hides all the rows with IDs that contain "celltohid" (if all the id's are `celltohid#`)... I don't know JavaScript, so below is my weak attempt at this. Every row with the unique ids "celltohid#" has a class "descexpand". So, I tried adding a toggle to change the display style for that class ... but it's not working...

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".search").on("keyup",function(){
                    var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                    $("#DMTbl tbody tr.contentrow").each(function(){
                        var lineStr = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                        if(lineStr.indexOf(searchTerm) === -1){
                            $(this).hide();
                        }else{
                            $(this).show();
                        }
                        var clasname = "descexpand";
                        var e = document.getElementByClass(clasnam);
                        if(e.style.display == "table-row") {
                            e.style.display = "none";
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
          </script>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You can get `css`property of particular row inside `else` part of `if(lineStr.indexOf...` i.e : `if($(this).css('display') != "table-row"){ //hide that tr }else { //show it}`

Comment: Making decisions based on partial string matches of ids is usually a bad idea. Instead, give those elements a CSS class. Also, you can use a CSS class to toggle the display of the row (e.g., `.hidden-row { display: none }`), then just use `.toggleClass('hidden-row', true | false)` to show/hide it.

Comment: Heretic Monkey ... that's a good way to deal with it... I'll see what I can do...

Comment: ... but my attempt didn't work... (see above)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `<td/>` id's for filtering. You can simply check the string in `<tr/>` and hide if there text doesn't exist.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".search").off('keyup').on("keyup", function() {
    var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $("table tbody tr").each(function(index) {
      var lineStr = $(this).text().toLowerCase();

      if (lineStr.indexOf(searchTerm) < 0) {
        $(this).hide();
      } else {
        $(this).show();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table> 
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>    
            <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
        </thead> 
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Smith</td>    
                <td>50</td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr>   
                <td>Eve</td>
                <td>Jackson</td>    
                <td>94</td> 
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<input class="search" type="text" />
```

Comment: Questions which explain changes made code are usually more useful (and therefore upvoted more often) than those which simply show code. See [answer] for more tipx.

Comment: Removing the .contentrow messes up some other things in the table.  (Basically, because the toggled element is ANOTHER tr).